# Parse a String dynamic in Twig

Tags: templating

I would like to output a field from a variable like this:

```
{% set foo = "entry.title" %}
{{ foo }}
```

In this example it outputs "entry.title".

Other Example like this:

```
{% set prefixVar = "en_" %}
{% set foo = "entry."~ prefixVar ~"title" %}
{{ foo }}
```

In this example it outputs "entry.en_title". Is it possible in Twig to get the content of the entry field instead of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surrounding text in quotes declares it as a string, whereas no quotes will assume variables. If you remove the quotes, you should get what you need.

```
{% set foo = entry.title %}
{{ foo }}
```

EDIT:

> I realy want to render a string and get the fieldvalue. A other example would be like this: I have a Variable with a Prefix and now i would like to output a field with this prefix: {% set foo = "entry."~ prefixVar ~ "_fieldName" %} {{ foo }}. Is that possible?

I am not sure if that's possible when accessing keys through the dot formatting (ie. `array.keyname`)

But you could tweak the approach a little bit, to access dynamic keys in `entry` using the `attribute()` twig function, such as:

```
{% set foo = attribute(entry, prefixVar~"_fieldName") %}
```

Comment: I realy want to render a string and get the fieldvalue. A other example would be like this: I have a Variable with a Prefix and now i would like to output a field with this prefix: {% set foo = "entry."~ prefixVar ~ "_fieldName" %} {{ foo }}. Is that possible?

Comment: Edited my answer, hopefully that should accomplish what you need!