# Is it possible to merge entry parameters to create a dynamic field handle?

Tags: matrix, fieldtypes

I'm trying to merge a field name prefix with entry.section to make a dynamic field handle. I'm guessing I'm setting the sectionMatrix variable incorrectly, causing the code to fail without error. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Channels:

- News
- Press

Each channel has is own matrix field, with different blocks:

- entryMatrixNews
- entryMatrixPress

Template Code:

```
{% set newsSectionIds = craft.entries.section('news').ids() %}
{% set pressSectionIds = craft.entries.section('press').ids() %}
{% set entryIds = newsSectionIds|merge(pressSectionIds) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.id(entryIds) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
   {% set sectionMatrix = 'entry.entryMatrix' ~ entry.section %}
   {# sectionMatrix then equals either entry.entryMatrixNews or entry.entryMatrixPress #}

   {% for block in sectionMatrix %}
      {# my matrix code #}
   {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Take a look on these two Answers: - http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12627/parse-a-string-dynamic-in-twig - http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13336/variable-variables-in-twig

Comment: Thanks Tom! The **attribute() twig function** example suggested by @taylor worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The [Twig attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) solved this for me. Thanks to @tom-bauer

Revised Template Code:

```
{% set newsSectionIds = craft.entries.section('news').ids() %}
{% set pressSectionIds = craft.entries.section('press').ids() %}
{% set entryIds = newsSectionIds|merge(pressSectionIds) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.id(entryIds) %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    {% set sectionMatrix = attribute(entry, "entryMatrix"~entry.section) %}

    {% for block in sectionMatrix %}

        {# my matrix code #}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can also use the subscript syntax: `entry["entryMatrix"~entry.section]`.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly, and is slightly shorter too.